# Can't resolve 'child_process'

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am currently on the backend of my software which runs via electron but I can't get the data. So I tried to retrieve the data from a python program that sends it using Flask, but when I run the npm start command it gives me the following error message:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\React\react-electron\src\pages'
```

Here is my Javascript and python script:

JS:

```
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.hello = require("child_process").spawn("python", ["./hello.py"]);
        this.state = { fs_s5: 12 };
        this.hello.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
          this.setState({ fs_s5: data });
        });
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <div class="home">
                <div class="template-1" id="temp1">
                <div class="panel-1">
                    <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1>Panel 1</h1>
                    <i class='bx bx-cog modal-trigger-panel'></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="sec-5 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-5">
                        <span class="h1" id="h1-fs-s5">{this.state.fs_s5}</span>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s5</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-4 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-4">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s4</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-3 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-3">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-2 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-2">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s2</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-1 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-1">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s1</h3>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Python:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World! This is powered by Python backend."

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(12)
   time.sleep(5)
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following in your `package.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  // add this to package.json 
  "browser": {
    "child_process": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I don't get the error at startup but after I run the npm start command there is nothing displayed when the page appears. It may be due to my package.json.

Comment: what makes changing the child_process value to 'false' work?

Comment: My understanding is that webpack tries to bundle the `child_process` module for the client code, running in the browser.  But the `child_process` is only available in Node.js. So setting it to `false` tells webpack that it's ok to use an empty module.